# Javascript to detect any wildcard url from certain domain (ex: google)

Tags: javascript, regex, redirect, path, wildcard

I am writing a simple if else if function. If prevPage contains any of 'accounts.google.com' redirect to homepage, else if not from 'accounts.google.com' redirect to login, as simple as that. I only need to detect if it contains 'accounts.google.com' but sometimes the url path is wildcard. if the url is 'accounts.google.com/blablabla' the if statement is at loss and not working

Comment: Any effort so far ? did you  tried anything please post the code too

Comment: Dear Code Maniac, I have updated my javascript code in the question, it is not working

Comment: The code you posted seems to give the desired result, can you explain where you're facing problem ?

Comment: I am writing a simple if else if function. If prevPage contains any of 'https://accounts.google.com' redirect to homepage, else if not from 'https://accounts.google.com' redirect to login, as simple as that. I only need to detect if it contains 'https://accounts.google.com' but sometimes the url path is wildcard. if the url is 'https://accounts.google.com/blablabla' the if statement is at loss and not working

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use URL api and check if host includes `google` or not

```js
let urls = ['https://accounts.google.co.id/accounts/SetSID', 'https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount=certainrandomparameters', 'https://accounts.google.com/blabla', 'google.com', 'xyz']

let domainDetector = (str) => {
  let newStr = /^https?:\/\//i.test(str) ? str : 'http://' + str
  let url = new URL(newStr)
  console.log(url.host.includes('google'))
}

urls.forEach(domainDetector)
```